# How do you at (@) someone in slack using the laravel slack notification api?

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, slack-api

I've got a functioning notification system that can post to Channel in our companies Slack.  However, everything that comes across is just text.  The [linkNames](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/SlackMessage.html) is suppose to find/link user names in your content.  I see that it gets set to "1" but has no affect when it shows up in the channel.

```
 namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SlackMessage;
class Dd extends Notification
{
use Queueable;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['slack'];
}


/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the Slack representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return SlackMessage
 */
public function toSlack($slackComment)
{   
    $slackMessage = new SlackMessage();
    $slackMessage->linkNames();
    $slackMessage->from('Christopher');
    $slackMessage->to($slackComment->channel);
    $slackMessage->content("Harded coded for example @christopher <- this doesn't get linked to the user in slack but should");
     $slackMessage->info();
    //dd($slackMessage); // this shows that the linkedNames attribute has been set to "1"
    return $slackMessage;             
}
```

}

[image: How it shows up in Slack]

Is this a known issues, a version mismatch, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-users

> To mention a user in app-published text, you need to provide their
>   user ID in the following syntax:
>
> ```
> Hey <@U024BE7LH>, thanks for submitting your report.
> ```

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz - it took me awhile to wrap my head around the idea that there are multiple APIs, the webhooks for sending messages and the api for getting information about channels/users etc  ...  seems like the default laravel slack notifier only provides access to the webhooks(?)